# Python show legend for iterations in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function inside a for loop. The function outputs two graphs `y` and `z` which are plotted in different figures. I want to create a legend where each value in `np.arange(0,20,5)` is shown in both `y` and `z` figures as `c = XXX` where XXX is the `c` used inside the for loop.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def functions(c,x):
    y = c*x
    z = 0.5*c*x**2
    return y,z

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(-5,5)

for c in np.arange(0,20,5):

    y,z = functions(c,x)

    ax1.plot(x, y, lw=2, label='')

    ax2.plot(x, z, lw=2, label='')


ax1.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=16)

ax2.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
ax2.set_ylabel('z', fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are plotting each value as a new line, you can just set your labels as your c value :

```
label = '%s'%c, ...
```

This means when you add a legend

```
ax2.legend()
```

It will display all the c-values within it.

Comment: Cool! `label = 'c=%s'%c` is what I wanted.